# How to create/add a column as a return output in an SQL select query based on another column's values?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case, calculated-columns

I have dynamically added a column (`industry_type`) to a SQL view using Case statement. Now I would like to use that same column name/values to add another dynamic column with `industry_group` output. I tried using the same method to create `industry_group` column. But I am unable to do so because the column created in view is not available in "main table".

Do I need to create a new column with `industry_group` at the source? Or is there a way to create that dynamically within the same view and return `industry_group` values?

Would be a great help if you could assist me with this problem.

Sample Code:

```
select 
    column 1, column 2, date,
    case
        when (column 1 like '%12321%' or column 2 like'%poultry%' 
           then 'Poultry Facilities'
        when (column 1  like '%43434%') or column 2 like'%Hospi%' 
           then 'Hospitals'
        else null
    end as [industry_type],
from table
```

Output:

```
Date        Industry Type
------------------------------
7/02/2021   Poultry facilities
7/02/2021   Poultry facilities
7/02/2021   Poultry facilities
10/02/2021  Poultry facilities
11/01/2021  Hospitals
10/01/2021  Hospitals
5/02/2021   Hospitals
```

Tried this script1:

```
select 
    column 1, column 2, date,
    case
       when (column 1 like '%12321%' or column 2 like'%poultry%' 
          then 'Poultry Facilities'
       when (column 1  like '%43434%') or column 2 like'%Hospi%' 
          then 'Hospitals'
       else null
    end as [industry_type],
    'PF' as industry_group,
from table
```

Output:

```
Date        Industry Type     Industry Group
----------------------------------------------
7/02/2021   Poultry facilities  PF
7/02/2021   Poultry facilities  PF
7/02/2021   Poultry facilities  PF
10/02/2021  Poultry facilities  PF
11/01/2021  Hospitals           PF
10/01/2021  Hospitals           PF
5/02/2021   Hospitals           PF
```

Tried script 2

```
select 
    column 1, column 2, date,
    case
       when (column 1 like '%12321%' or column 2 like'%poultry%' 
          then 'Poultry Facilities'
    end as [industry_type],
    'PF' as industry_group,
    case
       when (column 1  like '%43434%') or column 2 like'%Hospi%' 
          then 'Hospitals'
          else null
    end as [industry_type],
    'HOS' as industry_group,
from table
```

Unfortunately "Script 2" isn't working.

Desired output:

```
Date        Industry Type   Industry Group
---------------------------------------
7/02/2021   Poultry facilities  PF
7/02/2021   Poultry facilities  PF
7/02/2021   Poultry facilities  PF
10/02/2021  Poultry facilities  PF
11/01/2021  Hospitals          HOS
10/01/2021  Hospitals          HOS
5/02/2021   Hospitals          HOS
```

I have more than 10 search criteria against which I need to return the correct industry group

Please note: `industry_type` is not available in the "master table"

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  The view definition and your sample code would help too.

Comment: Hello @GordonLinoff, I've added sample code with desired output in my original post

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please put text or images instead of links.

Comment: Hi @M-Chen-3, its not allowing me to put text or images. Just link is allowed at the moment.

Comment: Well obviously you are able to put text, since you just edited it to a better format.

Comment: yup. i was able to put in text format. but initially it was coming up with the gibberish format. but later it showed up the way I wanted it to be. There's a hurdle always in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output doesn't seem to match the query: the query doesn't show any column date, I would expect an output with 3 columns:

```
Column1, column2, industry_type
```

Instead it has only 2

It would help if you paste the actual code instead of pictures from excel

Anyway to add a column in a select just add it among the fields:

```
SELECT column1,
column2,
case
...
END AS industry_type,
"PF" as industry_group
FROM table;
```

---

Update after question enhancement

Each column is a rule per se, if you want to make it depending on a previous one you should rewrite the rule twice, or making a nested query

First example

```
select 
    column 1, column 2, date,
    case
       when (column 1 like '%12321%' or column 2 like'%poultry%' 
          then 'Poultry Facilities'
       when (column 1  like '%43434%') or column 2 like'%Hospi%' 
          then 'Hospitals'
       else null
    end as [industry_type],
    case
       when (column 1 like '%12321%' or column 2 like'%poultry%' 
          then 'PF'
       when (column 1  like '%43434%') or column 2 like'%Hospi%' 
          then 'HOS'
       else null
    end as [industry_group],
from table
```

second example

```
Select
Date, industry_type,
Case
When industry_type = "Hospitals" then "HOS"
When industry_type = "Poultry facilities" then "POL"
...
End
As industry_group
FROM (
    select 
    date,
    case
       when (column 1 like '%12321%' or column 2 like'%poultry%' 
          then 'Poultry Facilities'
    end as [industry_type],
    case
       when (column 1  like '%43434%') or column 2 like'%Hospi%' 
          then 'Hospitals'
          else null
    end as [industry_type],
    from table)
```

Comment: Hello, 

I am unable to post my code like the way u did it above.

select coulumn 1, coulumn 2, date,
case
when (column 1 like '%12321%' or column 2 like'%poultry%' then 'Poultry Facilities'
when (column 1  like '%43434%') or column 2 like'%Hospi%' then 'Hospitals'
else null
end as [industry_type],
from table

I tried your suggestion, but its not giving me correct result. Ive posted again with 3 sample code and outputs in my original post.

Comment: See my update on answer, please do not cancel questions after people write answers and comments. We are spending time here.

Comment: Thanks. first example worked out well for me. appreciate your help.

Comment: Happy to hear that, than please mark the answer as accepted (flag near to the vote)